# pytest-ordering order modules not test case within module

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-cov

I have a list of test cases in different modules (just showing glimpse here, but in actual the count is around 10). 
I want pytest to execute these modules in order, First module-a.py, next module-b.py and so on... 
However, I am aware of ordering the test cases within module which is working perfectly fine.

Our overall application is a kind of pipeline where module-a output is consumed by module-b and so on..
We want to test it completely end-end in defined order of modules.

```
module-a.py
-----------
import pytest

@pytest.mark.run(order=2)
def test_three():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.run(order=1)
def test_four():
    assert True

module-b.py
-----------
@pytest.mark.run(order=2)
def test_two():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.run(order=1)
def test_one():
    assert True
```

From above code, I want 
module-a test_four, test_three
module-b test_one, test_two 
to be executed in order.

Currently we are running each of the module with --cov-append, something like below and generating final coverage.

```
pytest module-a.py
pytest --cov-append module-b.py
```

Can any one please help with better approach or better method.